# Remote Desktop 10.2.3 Database Creation Error; 10.2.1 runs fine; 10.2.2 crashes: how to find actual cause(s)?

Tags: high-sierra, remote-desktop

What would be good steps to find the cause of the below errors?

I get this error when running Microsoft Remote Desktop 10.2.3 or higher on MacOS High Sierra: [image]

```
Database Creation Error

"An error occurred during persistent store migration.

[Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, Code: 134110]"
```

I am stuck at 10.2.1 now (which cannot add user accounts and will eventually stop working), want to use the newer version, but cannot use intermediate 10.2.2 as it crashes with the below information that I repeatedly submitted with the "Problem Report for Microsoft Desktop".

Manually migrating all the machine and user entries is really cumbersome: there are hundreds of them.

Information that might help:

- where is the information on entries and users stored?
- what format is that information stored?
- are the tools for converting that information between various versions?
- where are crash reports stored?

Crash report on 10.2.1: https://gist.github.com/jpluimers/851453d938a62ce45abd30fb929ae5e1

Comment: Try the beta - just in case it fixes anything - https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/5e0c144289a51fca2d3bfa39ce7f2b06/ [you can have both at once on your machine] You also get a better line of communication for any issues you find.

Comment: @Tetsujin that does not crash, but `Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta.app` version `10.2.6`. only uses the entries I had in the database at the time I was using "Microsoft Remote Desktop.app" in the version 8.x era.

Any way to get the 10.x era entries in?

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea. Mine has the same entries whether I use the release or the beta.

Comment: Filed an issue on 20190111; no response yet, see thread at: https://twitter.com/jpluimers/status/1083678885940740096

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, it looks like the new versions don't like some formats of the old application library. I made my work again after rebuilding the data in the library, forcing a kind of fresh install:

1. Delete the faulty app. (Microsoft Remote Desktop)
2. I rename the folder `com.microsoft.rdc.macos`
   inside directory `/Users/myusername/Library/Containers/` to something like `old_com.microsoft.rdc.macos`

e.g.:

> `mv /Users/myusername/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.rdc.macos /Users/myusername/Library/Containers/old_com.microsoft.rdc.macos`

3. Reinstall Microsoft RDC and test.
4. If everything works fine, you can go back and delete the moved folder to just keep it clean. In my case `Users/myusername/Library/Containers/old_com.microsoft.rdc.macos`

Note: I bet if you only execute the step 2, while the application has been closed, it will work.

Comment: I've reformatted your answer so I hope the example and the explanation are now in sync. From what I see here, I will end up with an empty configuration. It does explain the configuration directory, so now at least I have a place to start digging on how to keep as much original data as possible.